# How do I use row values as the name of the columns in R?

Tags: r, merge

I have two data in R. the first one has one row(obs) and 700 variables (columns)

I have almost 700 ingredients, so it looks like this:

```
             1     2    3   4   .....
Cookbooks   ham  flour oil ...  ......
```

I would like to make the ingredients the variable names. So that it looks like this (just column names)

```
Cookbooks   ham  flour oil ...  ......
```

After that, I would like to merge this data in R with another data that I have that contains this:

```
Author    Pubyear        Title 
Simon Red    1992      Carbonara
Alex white   1980      roast chicken
........     .....     ............
```

It goes on. The final results should look like this with  he columns from data set 1 containing ingredients attached on the second dataset. This is my first question so I do apologise if I have done something wrong, happy to learn. thanks everyone

```
  Author    PubYear        Title       ham    flour   oil   .....   ......
Simon Red    1992      Carbonara        0       0      0  
Alex white   1980      roast chicken    0       0      1    .....   ......
........     .....     ............
```

I tried a bunch of codes I found in here but I always get an error message.
I am new to R, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your first (`ingredients`?) isn't quite clear: if what we see in your second code block are the column names, what exactly do the rows contain?

Comment: What's the connection between `Cookbooks` and `Author`, i.e. similar column?

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY cookbooks are the name of the dataset I Used but as you can see these are ingredients. Once I moved the ingredients as column names and merged them with the second dataset I can create a dummy variable. The recipe contains that specific ingredient it gets one, otherwise 0. Let me know if like this is clearer :)

Comment: @AndreWildberg no connection, once3 I merged the two I can start creating a dummy variable if a recipe contains that specific ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not assuming your `ingredients` table guarantees that `ham` (for instance) is always in column 2 across all rows. To work with this, I'll expand your sample a little

```r
ingredients <- read.table(text="
             1      2    3   4
Cookbooks   ham   flour oil ...
Cookbooks2  flour egg   ... ...")
```

where dots (here) mean "not included".

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble::rownames_to_column(ingredients, "Cookbook") %>%
  pivot_longer(-Cookbook) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  mutate(z = 1L) %>%
  filter(grepl("\\w", value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(Cookbook, names_from = "value", values_from = "z", values_fill = list(z = 0))
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   Cookbook     ham flour   oil   egg
#   <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 Cookbooks      1     1     1     0
# 2 Cookbooks2     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the ..... symbolizes more observations. I should have been clearer, sorry. Let me know if something else is not clear and thank for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: Similarly ... let me know if this does not work for (part of) your question. I had inferred that `...` might mean that, in which case ... it doesn't matter, and you may be able to remove the `filter(grepl("\\w", value))` from this pipe.

Comment: Does this work with your real data?

Comment: Sorry I just checked my stackoverflow. Thanks for your help r2evans. It didn't work the way I was picturing it so this is what I did instead. Item is the variable that contains all the ingredients. So because ingredients were listed vertically for each recipe, I grouped all the different columns and put all the ingredients (Item) into a unique cell. This is the command I used:

cookbooks4 <- cookbooks2 %>% group_by(Title, Author, Work, PubYear) %>% summarize(SIZE = n(), Item = paste(unique(as.character(Item)), collapse = ',') )

Comment: Now I am trying to create columns for each unique ingredient and I am trying to create a dummy if the ingredient is listed in that specific row. Struggling with that tho. This is what I used:

`library(stringr)
final <- strsplit(cookbooks4$Item, split = ",")
Item <- unique(str_trim(unlist(t)))
final2 <- as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(Item, function(i) sapply(t, function(j) +(any(grepl(i, j), na.rm = TRUE))))))
names(final2) <- item

But I am getting this error:
`Error in stri_trim_both(string) : argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)`